# Dell XPS 15 - can't turn wireless on (shaded out)

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Question regarding my wireless feature.  For some reason when I click on windows mobility center and no longer have the option of turning on my wireless signal.  It's off and the "turn on" button is greyed out.  How can I check to make sure my wifi still works or at a minimum turn it back on.

Comment: Isn't there a button that enables/disables the wireless signal?

Comment: Fn + F2 should be the keyboard combination to turn your wireless on and off http://www.hardwareheaven.com/reviewimages/dell-xps-l501x/dell-xps-l501x_keyboard.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Migrating from the comments...

Use Fn + F2 to turn the wireless on.  That's the hardware keyboard shortcut that is independent of the operating system.

[image]
(From hardwareheaven.com)